# Java binary available, but still "No such file or directory"

Tags: java, docker

When I run the command I got the error:

```
root@1290ff36814b:/opt/airflow/dags# python test.py
/opt/spark-3.3.1/bin/spark-class: line 71:  /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java: No such file or directory
/opt/spark-3.3.1/bin/spark-class: line 96: CMD: bad array subscript
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    .appName('test') \
  File "/opt/spark-3.3.1/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 269, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/opt/spark-3.3.1/python/pyspark/context.py", line 483, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/opt/spark-3.3.1/python/pyspark/context.py", line 195, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/opt/spark-3.3.1/python/pyspark/context.py", line 417, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/opt/spark-3.3.1/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 106, in launch_gateway
    raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

This is a docker container and /opt/jdk1.8.0 is a volume, and the volume is visible inside container and also de java binary.

```
root@1290ff36814b:/opt/airflow/dags# ls -l /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 uucp 143 8464 Dec 15  2018 /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
root@1290ff36814b:/opt/airflow/dags# ls -l /opt/jdk1.8.0/
total 25996
-r--r--r-- 1 uucp 143     3244 Dec 15  2018 COPYRIGHT
-r--r--r-- 1 uucp 143       40 Dec 15  2018 LICENSE
-r--r--r-- 1 uucp 143      159 Dec 15  2018 README.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 uucp 143   112724 Dec 12  2018 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
-r--r--r-- 1 uucp 143   153824 Dec 15  2018 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 uucp 143     4096 Dec 15  2018 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 uucp 143      132 Dec 15  2018 include
-rw-r--r-- 1 uucp 143  5211154 Dec 12  2018 javafx-src.zip
drwxr-xr-x 5 uucp 143     4096 Dec 15  2018 jre
drwxr-xr-x 5 uucp 143     4096 Dec 15  2018 lib
drwxr-xr-x 4 uucp 143       47 Dec 15  2018 man
-rw-r--r-- 1 uucp 143      424 Dec 15  2018 release
-rw-r--r-- 1 uucp 143 21105955 Dec 15  2018 src.zip
root@1290ff36814b:/opt/airflow/dags#
```

Why this happen?

I already tried to set JAVA_HOME and PATH, but still the same problem.

Comment: (in the container) do `ldd /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java` to see if the libraries needed by the `java` program are (all) present and valid.

Answer (score 0):

I just realize it has one space inside my python code where I export the `JAVA_HOME`. After remove it finally the code worked.

```
import os
import sys

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"]='/opt/spark-3.3.1'
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"]=' /opt/jdk1.8.0'
sys.path+=[os.environ["SPARK_HOME"]+"/python"]
sys.path+=[os.environ["SPARK_HOME"]+"/python/build"]
sys.path+=[os.environ["SPARK_HOME"]+"/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip"]
```